# Is there a reason why I am not able to see the last ECHO statement?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Please see the attached code.. For some reason I cannot understand why the last 2 statements are not popping up. I would love some guidance on this particular issue.

```
@ECHO off
SET user=%1%
SET password=%2%
SET server=%3%
ECHO Running MaintenanceToolsAPI.StartProcess
FOR /F "tokens=1-8" %%a IN ('maintenance_tools -user %user% -password %password% -server %server% -startprocess DataWarehouseSync') DO (
    IF "%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g"=="Process 'DataWarehouseSync' is being run with PID" (
        SET PID=%%h
    ) ELSE (
        EXIT /B 1
    )
)
ECHO The PID is %PID%
ECHO We have reached the end
```

Just as an FYI, the expected result for the command inside the FOR is:

```
Running maintenance_tools.gsp
Connecting as [user] to URL [server]
Running process 'DataWarehouseSync'
Process 'DataWarehouseSync' is being run with PID 16727
done
```

Comment: probably because of the `exit /b 1` statement. You can set one more echo right before the `exit` to see if the if goes there.

Comment: Apologies for not providing the expected output, but it should pass the IF condition and not go inside the ELSE.

Comment: Do an `echo "%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g" before the `if` line. Is the output, what you expect it to be?

Comment: Command line parameters are referenced as `%1`, `%2` etc. `%1%` works because the parser sees `%1` and then an additional `%`, which is "Start of a variable". As it doesn't find a "closing" `%`, the parser ignores the additional `%`. But nevertheless `%1%` is a wrong syntax (although "forgiven" by the parser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
....
SET server=%3

SET "PID="

ECHO Running MaintenanceToolsAPI.StartProcess
FOR /F "tokens=1-8" %%a IN ('maintenance_tools -user %user% -password %password% -server %server% -startprocess DataWarehouseSync') DO (
    IF "%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g"=="Process 'DataWarehouseSync' is being run with PID" (
        SET PID=%%h
    )
)

IF NOT DEFINED PID EXIT /B 1

ECHO The PID is %PID%
...
```

Given (your code) :

When the line `Running maintenance_tools.gsp` is processed,

%%a will become `Running`
%%b will become `maintenance_tools.gsp`
%%c..%%g will be empty, so

`"%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g"=="Process 'DataWarehouseSync' is being run with PID"` will be `false` so the `else` path is taken and the process finishes.

Solution - force `PID` to empty, then if any of the lines match the required string, `PID` will become *something* and hence when the `for` finishes, `PID` will be defined. `Exit b 1` if it is not, else report and continue.

Note also that parameter references (%0..%9) should be used as (eg) `set var=%3` or preferably `set "var=%3"`, not `%3%` as you expressed it.